Need to enable FastWebView using itext-java
I'm trying to enable fastweb view in pdf using java but not able to find any example in itext documentation.
Please help me out if anyone has done..
Thanks
Need to enable FastWeb view which will appear on pdf document properties.

I'm not familiar with the term, but I'm guessing this means Linearization. If it is the case, then this is a function not yet supported by iText.

Indeed, FastWebView is Adobe's term for PDF Linearization.
